# Select data using join table

Tags: sugarorm

Is there a programatic way to do a select with join table?

I did the workaroud of SugarRecord.findWithQuery(Class, query) but I'm curious for a better way

Comment: I thought that providing `Class` as first argument to the `findWithQuery` command will return only the class fields but that was not the case. You should specify the appropriate fields to be returned in the select query, specially clash with id column is very common & you might end up picking wrong ids from the result.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet.. We should build it soon, though. Right now the QueryBuilder is slightly limited.

Comment: is there a solution to execute raw query in sugar orm and then cast the result in an object?

Answer (score -1):

No you can't yet but what I suggest is do basic operations using Sugar then for complex queries just use android way.

```
public class CustomQuery extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

 private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "sugar_example.db";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

 public CustomQuery(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }
}
```